# Html, how to import / use toastr.js

Tags: javascript, html, toastr

I've got a little problem here. I think the solution is pretty simple and I'm just overseeing something.

So, my problem is, that I'm trying to use toastr.js on my webpage.
What I've got so far:

```
<link href="{% static "flat/css/toastr.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

(Which obviously points to the toastr.min.css file) and

```
<script src="{% static "flat/js/toastr.js" %}" ></script>
```

(Which points to the toastr.js file).

Now just before `</body>` I've got

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        toastr.options={"closeButton": false,"debug": false,"newestOnTop":  true,"progressBar": true,"positionClass": "toast-bottom-full-width","preventDuplicates": false,"onclick": null,"showDuration": "300","hideDuration": "1000","timeOut": "5000","extendedTimeOut":"1000","showEasing": "swing","hideEasing": "linear","showMethod": "fadeIn","hideMethod": "fadeOut"};
        toastr[success]("Message will come here", "Title");}
    );
</script>
```

So, I want to use toastr to display a notification when the page is loaded.
How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Whats happening now? Nothing? Got any errors? Shouldn't it be `toastr.success("message will come here" ,"title");`?

Comment: @putvande no, I got no errors at all

Comment: @putvande and I already tried toast.success, but the result was exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

You are using an undefined variable `success` that should be a string when used in `[]` notation or just a property name in dot notation

Try

```
toastr['success']("Message will come here", "Title");
```

Or

```
toastr.success("Message will come here", "Title");
```

Comment: Nope, they both didn't fix the issue.

Comment: should I use `toastr.success("Message will come here", "Title");` or `$(document).ready(function() { toastr.success("Message will come here", "Title"); )}` ?

Comment: Use inside ready as shown in question. Look in browser dev tools network to make sure both css and js resources are loading

Comment: Yea, I think the issue was, that the toastr.js file wasn't loaded!

Comment: You said there were no errors but that isn't really possible.

Comment: Yea, I think because of this (by the way it still does not work): If I check the resources, It doesn't give me the toastr.js file, but if I click on the link (flat/js/toastr.js) in the resources tab, It displays the file, so it has to be there

Comment: Also, in my django server console it doesn't list a request to toastr.js although it should get "imported" from the html file... And placing the file in another directory still changes nothing

Comment: Ok, now after I put ´<script src="{% static "flat/toastr.js" %}" type="text/javascript" />´ inside the ´<header>´ it works. Don't know why, but at least the file shows up in the resources tab. But now everything inside ´<body>´ isn't showing up :| EDIT: Found the / one "problem": After i import the file, everything after won't get loaded...

Comment: No, nothing at all, but now, I have this: I used the files toastr.min.js and toastr.js.map from the github repo, imported the .min.js after the <script> and now, it loads toastr.js. EDIT: But only as long I use toastr["success"], so I guess I have to import it before the script...

Comment: well yes..that's a given. You can't use code that is dependent on a library if library isn't loaded first

Comment: On their github repo, they tell you to install it with nuGet / npm / Bower, but why? I guess I could just use the .js and .css files directly from their repo (I mean I download them and reference them from my html site)!?